# Want to get the products with their categories in PDF

Tags: category-products, pdf, pdp

I want to get the all products for all categories with the products details include image, size weight , price in one pdf

Please help me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third party extensions that will allows you to download the catalog in a single PDF with required data.

**Here are the references:**

https://www.magedelight.com/pdf-catalog-print-advance-magento-2.html
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-print-catalog-plugin/

Apart from that if you want a customized system then you can create your own module where you will have to fetch all products collection & based on that you will print all the required data to the PDF from the fetched product/entity.

**Here is the reference to create the PDF:**

https://meetanshi.com/blog/generate-pdf-programmatically-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Lookbook and PDF catalog creator in store manager for magento is what you need. can be customized and is completely free for 14 days